# How to configure the display of characters .,;:/\{}[]()<>~*&?^%$#@!~`'"| on separate keyboard buttons for each character on Windows?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I'm wondering if it is possible to implement the output of each of the characters `` .,;:/\{}[]()<>~*&?^%$#@!~`'"| `` with a single click on one programmed button. Is it necessary for this can change the purpose of an existing button or you can create a shortcut if there is a keyboard with additional keys. And if it is possible how to make the output independent of the language layout of the keyboard. Maybe there is software with which you can do this.

Comment: [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) should be able to do this...

Comment: Super @DavidPostill, just what i need!